# python: how to handle timestamps (ISO8601)

Tags: python, timezone, timestamp

I have to deal in python with strings representing [iso8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) timestamps.

My timestamps string are therefore in the following form:

```
timestamp = "2011-08-18T10:29:47+03:00"
```

Currently I'm converting them in python using:

```
timestamp = timestamp[:-6]
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

But in this way I lose all the information about the time zone.
I have seen many examples here on s-o about timestamps and python, unfortunately no one was preserving the timezone as well, or just recover the time zone delay using:

```
delay = timestamp[-6:]
```

I have also tried:

```
timestamp = "2011-08-18T10:29:47+03:00"
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

but it returned

```
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

Can you give some insight?

Comment: you might mean [Internet Date/Time Format described in rfc 3339 (a profile of iso 8601)](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6)

Comment: related: [ISO to datetime object: 'z' is a bad directive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20194496/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [python iso8601](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/) module is built with a wonderful parse_date method that can handle timezone info :

```
>>> import iso8601
>>> iso8601.parse_date("2007-01-25T12:00:00Z")
datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 25, 12, 0, tzinfo=<iso8601.iso8601.Utc ...>)

>>> iso8601.parse_date("2011-08-18T10:29:47+03:00")
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 18, 10, 29, 47, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '+03:00'>)
```

If you want to convert it in another timezone, use the [astimezone(tz)](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.astimezone) method

If you need to get the UTC datetime you can use the [utctimetuple()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.utctimetuple) method.

Comment: Cool. Can you tell me how to convert the result to UTC+0?

Comment: @user601836 : I updated my answer with 2 solutions to convert the date obtained

Comment: I don't recommend using that library. The last update was 2007, and it doesn't accept all valid formats.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an external module that provides timezone support; the [`pytz` module](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) provides you with the necessary timezone database.

You'll either need to parse the timezone by hand to construct a pytz timezone, or use a package like [`zc.iso8601`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.iso8601/) or [`iso8601`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/) to do the parsing for you:

```
from zc.iso8601.parse import datetimetz
datetimetz(timestamp)
```