# How to parse a string like '2016-08-01 13:39:00+05:30' into datetime object of python

Tags: python, datetime

I am getting below error while trying to do this

```
from datetime import datetime 

time1 = '2016-08-01 13:39:00+05:30'
x = datetime.strptime(time1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
print(x)
```

Error is ...

```
ValueError: time data '2016-08-01 13:39:00+05:30' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
```

Comment: try to remove the blank between %S and %z

Comment: + replace '/' with '-'

Comment: didn't worked ...ValueError: time data '2016-08-01 13:39:00+05:30' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'

Comment: I replaced the '/' with '-', it is still not working

Comment: `%z` does not even work on my computer.. What version of Python are you using? Anyway, [it's not recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12282040/5018771) to use timezones in strptime

Comment: read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194496/iso-to-datetime-object-z-is-a-bad-directive

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 2 or early versions of Python 3 (3.0 and 3.1), you can use the [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for converting a string to a timezone aware object.

The code to do this is simple:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dt = dateutil.parser.parse('2016-08-01 13:39:00+05:30')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 1, 13, 39, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800))
```

---

If you are using Python 3.2 or later, the `%z` option has been added as a formatting option when parsing a date. You can accomplish this task without using `dateutil` in these versions by doing this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-08-01 13:39:00+0530', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 1, 13, 39, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 19800)))
```

Unfortunately, you do have to strip the colon (`:`) from the offset for this to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

this works in python 3.4, conforms to the datetime documentation

```
from datetime import datetime

time1 = '2016-08-01 13:39:00+0530'
x = datetime.strptime(time1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
print(x)
```

gives

```
2016-08-01 13:39:00+05:30
```

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs `%z` uses the form +HHMM or -HHMM

Comment: to make it work you should remove the last ':' `time2 = ':'.join(time1.split(':')[:-1]) + time1.split(':')[-1]`

Comment: Yes, I altered input data without thinking, Isn't it strange that the printed value cannot be parsed back by `datetime`? isn't there a bug or improvement for python?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [dateparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser):

```
>>> dateparser.parse('2016-08-01 13:39:00+05:30')
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 1, 13, 39)
>>> dateparser.parse('2016-08-01 13:39:00+05:30', settings={'TO_TIMEZONE': 'UTC'})
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 1, 8, 9)
```