# python: convert pywintyptes.datetime to datetime.datetime

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I am using pywin32 to read/write to an Excel file. I have some dates in Excel, stored in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. I would like to import those into Python as datetime.datetime objects. Here is the line of code I started with:

```
prior_datetime = datetime.strptime(excel_ws.Cells(2, 4).Value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

That didn't work. I got the error:

```
strptime() argument 1 must be str, not pywintypes.datetime
```

I tried casting it to a string, like so:

```
prior_datetime = datetime.strptime(str(excel_ws.Cells(2, 4).Value), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

That didn't work either. I got the error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00
```

So then I tried something a little different:

```
prior_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(excel_ws.Cells(2, 4).Value))
```

Still no luck. Error:

```
TypeError: a float is required.
```

Casting to a float didn't help. Nor integer. (Hey, I was desperate at this point.)

I might be looking in the wrong plce, but I'm having a terrible time finding any good documentation on pywin32 in general or pywintypes or pywintypes.datetime in particular.

Any help?

Comment: can you show us what the string looks like?

`str(excel_ws.Cells(2, 4).Value)`

Comment: Have you considered using `openpyxl`? It doesn't require a version of Excel to be installed or automated and handles converting cells with dates to  the native python datetime for you...

Comment: Sure. I just threw in a print statement, and this is what it looks like:

2016-04-01 17:29:25+00:00

Now I feel silly for not doing that earlier. If it's always going to add a '+00:00' on the end, clearly I can use a simple splice and get what I need.

However, I still would like to know if there's a better way to handle this.

Comment: I hadn't, Jon. The advantage of not needing Excel to be installed doesn't do much for me since I have Excel installed, use it every day, and so on.

If PyWin32 continues to irritate me with lack of documentation, however, I may very well check it out soon.

(I was using xlrd and xlwt before this, but xlwt can't handle .xlsx, and I figured: why use xlrd and PyWin32 when I could just use PyWin32? So that's how I got where I'm at.)

Comment: Don't have a windows box but this is the closest thing I could find. I know it uses `pywintypes.Time` instead of `.datetime` but worth a shot. http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/use-a-pytime-value.html#from-elements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the problem is the `+00:00` timezone offset. [Looking into this there's not an out of the box solution for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194496/iso-to-datetime-object-z-is-a-bad-directive)

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-04-01 17:29:25+00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 324, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
```

One band-aid solution is to strip the timezone but that feels pretty gross.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-04-01 17:29:25+00:00".rstrip("+00:00"), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 17, 29, 25)
```

Looking around it looks like (if you can use a third party library) `dateutil` solves this issue and is nicer to use then `datetime.strptime`.

## On Commandline

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

## code

```
>>> import dateutil.parser                                                      
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("2016-04-01 17:29:25+00:00")
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 17, 29, 25, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. 

For tonight, I just stripped out the timezone. Agreed, it feels gross.

For future (I'm going to continue to develop this), I'm going to look into dateutil.

I hate date/time issues in general, so that might be helpful.

Thanks for your research and solution.

Comment: instead of "2016-04-01 17:29:25+00:00".rstrip("+00:00"), we should use "2016-04-01 17:29:25+00:00".rsplit("+00:00")[0]. Using rstrip removes all combinations of matching characters, which can have some unintended consequences, http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 8):

I think you were quite close with the `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`. Taking that approach all the way, you could transform your `pywintypes.datetime` object to a timestamp using its `timestamp` method. To be safe with time zones, also use the `tzinfo` attribute. See `In [4]:` below for the full syntax.

I just ran into the same issue when trying to make a pd.DataFrame out of a few rows of an Excel book. I kept getting this terrible Python has stopped working" dialog box.

```
In [1]: pywindt
Out[1]: pywintypes.datetime(2018, 9, 13, 14, 2, 24, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True))

In [2]: str(pywindt)
Out[2]: '2018-09-13 14:02:24+00:00'

In [3]: # Conversion takes place here!

In [4]: dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
   ...:     timestamp=pywindt.timestamp(),
   ...:     tz=pywindt.tzinfo
   ...: )

In [5]: dt
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 13, 14, 2, 24, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True))

In [6]: str(dt)
Out[6]: '2018-09-13 14:02:24+00:00'
```

As a follow up, if you need to check whether or not a cell value is a pywintypes datetime, the following should be good enough.

```
In [7]: import pywintypes

In [8]: isinstance(pywindt, pywintypes.TimeType)
Out[8]: True

In [9]: # just out of curiousity

In [10]: isinstance(dt, pywintypes.TimeType)
Out[10]: False
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has a similar solution using `pd.Timestamp()`

Insert the `pywintype.datetime` object as the argument and set `unit='s'` (for Seconds, or enter whatever unit the timestamp is in).

For a pandas Series:

```
def convert(time):

    return pd.Timestamp(time.timestamp(), unit = 's')


newSeries = oldSeries.apply(convert)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a simple option for converting pywintypes.datetime to datetime.datetime

By adding any datetime.datetime type to the pywintypes.datetime will result in a cast to the datetime.dateime type. This can be done using a zero-delta for example.

For the case of the original question, the below can be used without requiring additional modules

```
desired_datetime_type = excel_ws.Cells(2, 4).Value + datetime.timedelta(0)
```

Comment: Your answer seemed VERY pythonic to me, but it did not convert to datetime.datetime object in my case.

Comment: @ThomIves Please share a snippet and python version you are using. I'm curious

Comment: Sorry! I think I solved the issue up or down-stream in JavaScript or somewhere else and can't remember now. I should've have given an example at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
prior_datetime = datetime.strptime((str(excel_ws.Cells(2, 4).Value)).rstrip("+00:00"), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of suggestions to use rstrip. I found that when the time ends in 00 that will not work.

```
>>> oltime='2020-06-21 19:50:00+00:00'
>>> str(oltime).rstrip("+00:00").strip()
'2020-06-21 19:5'
```

I sugest using replace instead

```
>>> str(oltime).replace('+00:00', '')
'2020-06-21 19:50:00'
>>>
```

This is because rstrip is removing all instaces of each charature starting from the left end of the string and working to the right:

```
>>> str(oltime).rstrip('+0:')
'2020-06-21 19:5'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the answer from Alex above, if you remove the space between the %S and %z, with python 3.8.3rc1 and datetime it works:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-04-01 17:29:25+00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 17, 29, 25, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the .rstrip of the timezone feels too gross you I have solution with regular expressions below.

Should be able to handle if a timezone actually is included in the returned number format!

```
from datetime import datetime
import re
def xldatetime_to_datetime(xl_datetime):
        """
        takes the str() value of a  pywintypes.datetime object and 
        converts it to a datetime.datetime object via regular expression
        """
        p = re.compile('(?<=\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}\s\d{2}(:\d{2}){2})\+\d{2}:\d{2}')
        #2021-07-12 08:26:04+00:00 -> 2021-07-12 08:26:04
        xl_datetime = p.sub('',xl_datetime)
        py_datetime = datetime.strptime(xl_datetime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return py_datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

AlexLordThorsen answer was very close. You have to match every character in the string with the correct directive. AlexLordThorsen code tried to match 'Space' string with timezone directive %z which is wrong. Below is image with better explanation

[image]

Below corrected code will work

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-04-01 17:29:25+00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 17, 29, 25, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(), which is probably the easiest way.

```
import datetime 

datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2016-04-01 17:29:25+00:00")
```