# Converting a pywintypes.datetime into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I am attempting to use `win32com` library to download outlook emails from a shared mailbox.

My code is below:

```
import win32com.client
import win32com
import pandas as pd
from unidecode import unidecode

import datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

folder = outlook.Folders.Item("My Shared Mailbox Name")
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")

msg = inbox.Items

subject = []
body = []
sender = []
sendermail = []
senttime = []

for message in msg:
    subject.append(message.Subject)
    body.append(message.Body)
    sender.append(unidecode(message.SenderName))
    sendermail.append(unidecode(message.SenderEmailAddress))
    senttime.append(message.SentOn)

maildata = pd.DataFrame({'Subject':subject,'Mail Body':body, 'Sender Email Address': sendermail, 'Sender Name': sender, 'Sent Time': senttime})
```

The error happens in the last line when I try and convert the lists into a DataFrame.

I receive below error:

```
AttributeError: 'pywintypes.datetime' object has no attribute 'nanosecond'
```

The time is extracted in a different format that what I am used to:

```
pywintypes.datetime(2020, 11, 24, 14, 59, 9, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True))
```

Since I am using `win32com` library, the time is extracted in `pywintypes.datetime` format which I am unable to convert into a format which can be added to a DataFrame.

I looked around and it seems that the documentation for win32com library isn't great.

I did find [Tim Golden's Python stuff](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i.html) and a few threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028290/python-convert-pywintyptes-datetime-to-datetime-datetime) which didn't solve the problem. I am sure its pretty much in front of my eyes and I am unable to put 2 and 2 together.

I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction on how to convert .

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a only a workaround, but you could convert the pywintypes.datetime to a string (and slice off the extra trailing characters) before converting it to a pandas datetime.

```
message = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6).Items.GetLast()
pd.to_datetime(str(message.senton)[:-6])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the timezone creates the problem.

```
key_time_var = 'Sent Time' ## The column containing the datetime data
df[key_time_var] = df[key_time_var].dt.tz_convert(None)
```

Something like this can remove the Timezone and then it should work

Comment: +1 
pandas do read the data, but than I couldn't even see the dataframe - this works and it's the simplest solution imho

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue.
My solution is as follows;

```
d = mail.receivedtime.date()
```

d will be like `datetime.date(2016, 4, 6`)

Also you can get

```
t = mail.receivedtime.time()
```

t will be like `datetime.time(23, 15, 13)`

And you combine them in this way:

```
newdate = datetime.datetime.combine(d,t)
```

Then you can get what you want!

I believe this is late answer for you, but I do hope it will be helpful for other people who faces the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.timestamp()` function on the `pywintypes.datetime` object and the convert the number to a Pandas-Timestamp using `pd.to_datetime`. It should be faster than making the conversion in Python.

```py
import win32com.client
import win32com
import pandas as pd

import datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

folder = outlook.Folders.Item("My Shared Mailbox Name")
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")

msg = inbox.Items

senttime = []
for message in msg:
    senttime.append(message.SentOn.timestamp())
    break

maildata = pd.DataFrame({'Sent Time': senttime})

maildata["Sent Time"] = pd.to_datetime(maildata["Sent Time"], unit="s")
maildata
```