# how to convert pywintypes.datetime to different format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pywin

I have an object `x` which is as below

```
x = '2020-06-15 00:00:00+00:00'

print(x)
2020-06-15 00:00:00+00:00
print(type(x))
<class 'pywintypes.datetime'>
```

I want to convert above object to `2020-06-15` format and also to `Year-Quarter format` i.e. `2020 Q2`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: review this links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028290/python-convert-pywintyptes-datetime-to-datetime-datetime

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe this can help you....

```
from math import ceil
x = '2020-06-15 00:00:00+00:00'
date, time = x.split()
yy, mm, dd = date.split('-')

print(f'{yy} - Q{ceil(int(mm)/3)}')
```

Comment: +1 as I borrowed your last line ;-) I think it is better though to work with the class methods instead of converting to string and then splitting the string etc.

Comment: Yeah, actually the asker already assumed to be having a string of datetime at some point of time, so I delivered a fool-proof solution right from that position

Answer (score 2):

you have methods available as you have for the [datetime.datetime class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), so you can use .year and .month attributes. Ex:

```
import math
# --- Windows-specific! ---
import pywintypes
import win32timezone

t = pywintypes.Time(1592179200).astimezone(win32timezone.TimeZoneInfo('UTC'))

print(t)
# 2020-06-15 00:00:00+00:00

print(f'{t.year}-Q{math.ceil(int(t.month)/3)}')
# 2020-Q2
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED 30-1-2023

The code below will help to convert your given time to your required time

```
import datetime as dt

_datetime_str = '2020-06-15 00:00:00+00:00'
_splitted_datetime_str = x.split("+")
# output: ['2020-06-15 00:00:00', '00:00']

_datetime = dt.strptime(_splitted_datetime_str[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# output datetime.datetime(2020, 06,15, 00, 00, 00)
```