# Aware iso 8061 to datetime Python

Tags: python, datetime, iso

I have as input following string:

```
input = "20170620015620.222+0000"
```

To convert it to `datetime`, I can use something like this:

```
utc_format_regex = re.compile('(?P<year>\d{4})'
                                      '(?P<month>\d{2})'
                                      '(?P<day>\d{2})'
                                      '(?P<hour>\d{2})'
                                      '(?P<minute>\d{2})'
                                      '(?P<second>\d{2})'
                                      '\.'
                                      '(?P<milisecond>\d{3})'
                                      '(?P<tz>\+\d{4})')
year, month, day, hour, minute, second, milisecond, tz = utc_format_regex.match(value).groups()
```

Parsing this to datetime seems easy, except param tzinfo ( I don't know, how to use it properly). That code won't work just because of such error:

```
TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'unicode'
```

```
datetime(year=int(year), month=int(month), day=int(day), hour=int(hour), minute=int(minute), second=int(second),
                                     microsecond=int(milisecond) * 1000, tzinfo=tz)
```

Comment: `input` shouldn't be used as a variable name

Comment: it isn't. I just typed it here. good point nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

Just use `strptime`:

```
import datetime
parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f%z')
```

Comment: A warning for python 2 users: `%f` may or may not be supported, depending on your OS and interpreter.

Comment: %z isn't supported under my version (or server version). Cannot do that, this is 2.7 Python

Comment: Here you have, why %z isn't working.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194496/iso-to-datetime-object-z-is-a-bad-directive?rq=1

Comment: Tough luck, you probably need `pytz` module then.

Comment: Seems, you can do  smth like:
'tz = int(tz[1:])/1000*3600'
'datetime(year=int(year), month=int(month), day=int(day), hour=int(hour), minute=int(minute), second=int(second),
                                     microsecond=int(milisecond) * 1000, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzoffset(None,tz))'

I do not know, what happens negative values though... Should it be negative number?

Comment: one mistake here, should be:

int(tz[1:])/100*3600

btw. Can you answer using pytz? I do not know conception. I'd be glad :)