# Python how to parse datetime with timezone?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to parse the following datetime value using datetime.strptime:

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-03-26T18:00:00+01:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%Sz")
```

But getting this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2018-03-26T18:00:00+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z'
```

From my reading of the documentation, `%z` should equate to the UTC offset, however if I change the format string to end `%S%z` I get a different error:

```
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

Although this question has been marked as a duplicate, I disagree. I am using Python 2.7 which as noted above does not accept the `%z` TZ format option, so the approaches mentioned in the comments did not work for me. I finally solved this by using the `dateutil` module as mentioned in this post: [ISO to datetime object: 'z' is a bad directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194496/iso-to-datetime-object-z-is-a-bad-directive)

I would therefore like to solve my own question although this seems impossible since the question has been marked a duplicate.

Comment: Remove the `':'` from the timezone

Comment: How best to do this? Should I format the string first and truncate, or?

Comment: Also note a missing `%`: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%Sz` should be `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z`

Comment: What people have been saying: `datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-03-26T18:00:00+0100", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")`.

Comment: I would do: oldstr = '2018-03-16T18:00:00+01:00', newstr = oldstr.replace(":", ""), d = datetime.datetime.strptime(newstr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%z).

Comment: You could do something like `s = '2018-03-26T18:00:00+01:00'
pos = s.rfind(':')
s[:pos] + s[pos+1:]`

Comment: When I try to convert the newly formatted datetime using `strptime` I get `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'`?? - looks like I'm hitting this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194496/iso-to-datetime-object-z-is-a-bad-directive