# How can I convert UTC format time "2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:00" to usual datetime object by datetime module?

Tags: python, datetime

There is a time string `2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:00` I got from front-end, and I want to convert it to a normal `datetime` object by using datetime

How can I do it correctly?

I tried

```py
start_time_utc_s = "2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:00"
r = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time_utc_s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+08:00")

# print(r)
# 2019-05-15 16:08:37
```

but I don't think it's right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not right because you're simply discarding the timezone information (in this case, the *UTC* offset (*+8* hours)). 
For more details, check [[Python 3.Docs]: datetime - strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) (***%z*** directive).

> ```py
> >>> import datetime
> >>>
> >>> start_time = "2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:00"
> >>>
> >>> dt0 = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+08:00")
> >>> dt0
> datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 15, 16, 8, 37)
> >>> dt0.tzinfo
> >>>
> >>> dt_format_string = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"  # This format string also takes timezone info (UTC offset) into account
> >>> dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, dt_format_string)
> >>> dt1
> datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 15, 16, 8, 37, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=28800)))
> >>> dt1.tzinfo
> datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=28800))
> >>>
> >>> dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:45", dt_format_string)  # Changed the offset to +08:45
> >>> dt2
> datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 15, 16, 8, 37, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=31500)))
> ```

The time offset in question corresponds to a bunch of timezones: *AWST*, *CST*, *HKT*, *IRKT*, *MYT*, *PHT*, *SGT*, *WITA*, ... (check [[TimeAndDate]: Time Zone Abbreviations – Worldwide List](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones) for the complete list).

***@EDIT0***:

Everything above is on *Python 3.**7**(.3)* (and it seems that **the doc and functionality are NOT in sync**). 
On *Python 3.**6**(.8)*:

> ```py
> >>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:45", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "c:\install\x64\python\python\03.06.08\Lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
>     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
>   File "c:\install\x64\python\python\03.06.08\Lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
>     (data_string, format))
> ValueError: time data '2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:45' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
> ```

For that, as shown in:

- [[SO]: ISO to datetime object: 'z' is a bad directive [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194496/iso-to-datetime-object-z-is-a-bad-directive)
- [[SO]: Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)
- [[SO]: Converting string with UTC offset to a datetime object [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609259/converting-string-with-utc-offset-to-a-datetime-object)

one way would be to (install and) use *dateutil*:

> ```py
> >>> import sys
> >>> sys.version
> '3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'
> >>>
> >>> from dateutil import parser
> >>> parser.parse("2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:00")
> datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 15, 16, 8, 37, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 28800))
> ```

Or you could strip out the (last) colon between hours and minutes (for *UTC* offset). Note that the below code relies on *UTC* offset being specified in the fixed format from the question:

> ```py
> >>> start_time = "2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:00"
> >>>
> >>> dt_format_string = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
> >>>
> >>> datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time[:-3] + start_time[-2:], dt_format_string)
> datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 15, 16, 8, 37, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 28800)))
> ```

But both these seem to be just workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it seemed I have to convert `+08:00` to `+0800` at first?

Comment: No, you don't. It works just fine. Try using the same format on some thext like *"2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:30"*, you'll notice that it will correctly compute the difference.

Comment: But  it failed in my trial , `ValueError: time data '2019-05-15T16:08:37+08:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'` as the doc said you mentioned above [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), I‘m using `python3.6`’

Comment: You're welcome. This behavior difference between versions surprised me :).